# Non-conjugate subgroups

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

I want to show that $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix} : \theta \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$ and $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 
t & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{t}
\end{pmatrix} : t >0 \right\}$ are not conjugate in $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. To do so, can I just say that the former has complex eigenvalues while the latter has real eigenvalues and conjugate matrices must have the same eigenvalues??

Comment: Even stronger: they're not isomorphic as abstract groups (since only the first has torsion) nor homeomorphic (since only the first is compact).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can argue in that way. Or you could say the first subgroup is compact, but the second isn't, or the first subgroup has nontrivial elements of finite order, but the second doesn't.

Comment: they're definitely both connected though, right?

Comment: Yes. Although one is simply connected and the other isn't.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Actually can you say why the difference in compactness means they can't be conjugate? Is it just because conjugation is continuous?

Comment: @okaskadasd conjugation by an element is a homeomorphism from $\text{SL}_2(\Bbb R)$ to itself.